# Change CSS for Jquery Mobile Listview

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to have a listview within jquery mobile with a filter search but instead of having the normal list we create a card view. So in other worlds we are still adding the `<li></li>` for the list but we are changing the list css to a class so that it shows like cards and not in its usual way.

Is that possible? do I need to disable some css or added a new class or something to that effect to ensure that the list looks different?

Comment: And what is a card view to you? There so many different implementations to look at.

Comment: The card view is the way google plus show posts like on a flat card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one implementation I was using: http://appcropolis.com/page-templates/list-of-cards/

I only hope it was updated to work with jQuery Mobile 1.3

Or you can eve do it by yourself if you know enough css. Only important thing is to change **`li`** width to lets say **50 %** (pr less if you want **`margins`**), set it to **`float left`** and and full border around them. And that is that, you can do it on any listview implementation.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/NBv9B/

**CSS:**

```
.ui-listview li {
    width: 44% !important;
    margin: 2% !important;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

Comment: This is cool but would it maintain the filter search or would that feature be broken

Comment: Filtering will stay the same. Put filter where ever you want, remember HTML was not changed, only CSS look. Functionality will be the same, only final look is different.